# Unable to Convert Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage mail message to System.Net.Mail.MailMessage

Tags: exchangewebservices, system.net.mail

Is there any way of converting Exchange EMailMessage to System.Net.Mail.MailMessage:

```
FindItemsResults<Item> result = exchange.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox,subjectFilter, new ItemView(10));
```

I have tried iterating through the result, but do not know how to proceed with the conversion:

```
foreach(Item item in result)
{
   EmailMessage message = EmailMessage.Bind(exchange, item.Id );
   String body = message.Body.Text;
   String mailSubject = message.Subject.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Here we like to see your attempt before considering answering. Please take a moment to read "[ask]" to increase your chance.

Comment: Thanks @GuillaumeRAYMOND for the edits. I have rephrased my question and it would be really helpful if you could provide some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly they are different types so you can't cast or covert them. You may want to consider accessing the MimeContent of the message https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-export-items-by-using-ews-in-exchange . This content can then be used parsed using MimeKit http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Parsing-Messages.htm#LoadMessage . MimeKit has the same type of functionality as System.Net.Mail.MailMessage if your just trying to resend a Message via SMTP.

Comment: It must be noted that the MIME content might not preserve all the MAPI specific properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer the attributes one by one like that

```
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
        mail.From = new MailAddress(exchangeEmail.From.Address);
        mail.Subject = exchangeEmail.Subject;

        foreach(EmailAddress address in exchangeEmail.ToRecipients)
        {
            mail.To.Add(address.Address);
        } ...
```

and put it in a function that takes a ews email message as a parameter.